# SubForm Select Row and Edit Source

Tags: ms-access, vba, subform

I have a SubForm ("Main Menu SubForm") that is on a MainForm ("Main Menu")... I want to select a row on the SubForm and it then pull the corresponding row into another form for edit.

I have the following code but it doesn't seem to do what I expect:

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()
    Me.Requery
    If IsLoaded("Main Menu") Then
        If Forms![Main Menu]![Main Menu SubForm].Form.RecordsetClone.RecordCount > 0 Then
            DoCmd.GoToControl "txtWOrderID"
            DoCmd.FindRecord Forms![Main Menu]![Main Menu SubForm].Form![WOrderID]
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I have attached a link to my database for reference if needed:
[Access Invoice System](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/93855068/TriadTechx.accdb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up getting it to work by doing this from the Main Form:

```
Private Sub btnViewWorkOrder_Click()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Work Order", acNormal, , "[WOrderID] = '" & Forms![Main Menu]![txtWOrderID] & "'", acFormEdit, acDialog
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like (and this is aircode, so it needs tweaking):

```
forms!WOrderID.RecordSource = "Select * from MyTable where WOrderID = " & me.txtWOrderID & ""
Forms!wOrderID.Refresh
```

Comment: Not sure I am following the code... can you be more specific? Am I using it like this:  forms! ***Work Order ID from Destination*** .RecordSource = "Select * from ***Main Menu SubForm*** where WOrderID = " & me.txtWOrderID & ""
Forms! ***Work Order ID from Destination*** .Refresh

Comment: If WOrderID is not an Integer field, you need to surround your variable with single quotes.  Not sure if that matters.  Also, if your field/form names have spaces, don't forget to surround them with brackets.  The RecordSource should be worded exactly like a query would be, because in essence you're binding the form to a query.

Comment: I am obviously still doing something wrong... can you look at my database and see what I might be doing wrong. This is what I updated it to and it still doesn't work. I think I am putting something in the wrong spot. `Private Sub Form_Activate()
    Forms![Work Order].RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM [Work Order] WHERE [WOrderID] = '" & Me.txtWOrderID & "'"
    Forms![Work Order].Refresh
End Sub`

Comment: Can't do it from work, they have us locked down.  It looks right, except if it's a Subform it actually needs to be referenced differently.  Take a look here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/113352